# Safari URL bar discoloration

Tags: macos, safari, color

In Safari (12.0.3 and probably earlier) the URL bar can have an element of discoloration. I think is partially driven by the content/colors of the page being displayed as the amount of discoloration changes from page to page and appears to be stronger for pages that have darker colors below the section that is discolored.

Unfortunately this discoloration can mimic the symptoms of macula degeneration if you are glancing at this spot on the screen.  As such I want to get rid of it.

How can I turn this discoloration off?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

System Prefs > Accessibility > Display > Reduce Transparency.

You can search it with 'reduce'.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that did it.  But I never would have thought to opt-out of an accessibility feature to do this.  I was looking in the Safari and display preferences.  Also it is misleading as it really has nothing to do with transparency.

Comment: It's system-wide. Most obvious one is the menu bar goes solid colour too

Comment: @PeterM It used to not be in the Accessibility pane. But since it became a more widespread item they decided it counts as an accessibility problem. And it does have everything to do with transparency.